# JavaScript smooth scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can somebody tell me whats wrong with this code...  I used this code on one website and it worked fine.. I'm trying to use it again but it doesn't work.
I always get this error 
jquery.min.js:140 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('click', "a[href^='#']", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
            }, 500);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `a[href^='#']` to `a[href='\\\\#']` works for me. I'm assuming it's because `#` is used as an identifier for IDs and needs to be escaped.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', "a[href^='\\\\#']", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't think it's a root cause. It's very common to select like $("a[href^='#']")

Comment: It's common, but https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ says:
> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \\